# awk + print awk output in one line

Tags: awk, ksh

When I run the following **hasys** command with **awk** , I get output with machines names as the following:

```
hasys -display|grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1}'
  machine1a
  machine1b
```

please advice how to print the machines names in one line as the following: example

```
hasys -display|grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1}'

    machine1a machine1b
```

what I need to add in my awk syntax so I will able to print the names in one line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can say:

```
hasys -display | grep Shutdown | awk '{print $1}' ORS=' '
```

Answer (score 10):

The `grep` with `awk` is redundant:

```
 hasys -display | awk '/Shutdown/ { printf "%s ", $1 }'
```

Comment: If he wants a newline after the last record, he could do: `awk '/Shutdown/ {printf "%s ", $1} END {print ""}' `

Answer (score 6):

```
hasys -display | awk '/Shutdown/ {print $1}' | paste -sd ' ' -
```

Contrary to [@devnull's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115608/22565) and [@jasonwryan's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115610/22565), this one doesn't add a trailing space and terminates the line. `paste -sd<sep> -` is the generic idiom to join lines into a `<sep>` separated list.

Answer (score 3):

```
 echo $( hasys .. the whole thing )
```

Just for fun